# I am having an issue writing a function in Javascript.

Tags: javascript, function

I have been learning c++ all semester and have no clue how to edit my code to run with a function instead of just the way that the javascript is written. I need to write a function for the mathematical section so that it's output appears in the total section for the design.  The code that I have is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>The Bean Counter</title> 
<style type="text/css">
         body {background-color : saddlebrown; color : darkorange; 
                   font-family : helvetica; text-align : center}
         table {margin-left : auto; margin-right : auto; text-align : center; 
                   background-color : #993300; border-style : solid;
                   border-color : firebrick; border-width : medium; padding : 8px }
   </style>
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <script type = "text/javascript"> 
       var shots = 1; 
       var drink = "none"; 
       var ounce = 0; 
    </script>
    <h1 style="color : white"> The Bean Counter</h1> 
    <hr style="width : 50%; color : darkorange  "/> 
    <p><b>Figuring the price of espresso drinks<br /> 
                so baristas can have time to chat</b></p> 
    <form action="" > 

    <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="1" onclick='shots = 1'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="8oz" onclick='ounce = 8'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="    ESPRESSO    " onclick='drink = "espresso"'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="Clear" onclick=
             'shots = 1;
             drink = "none";
             ounce = 0;
             document.forms[0].price.value = "0.00"
           '/>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type = "button" value="2" onclick = 'shots = 2'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type = "button" value = "12oz" onclick = 'ounce = 12'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" value="      LATTE      " onclick='drink = "latte"'/>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type = "button" value = "3" onclick = 'shots = 3'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type = "button" value = "16oz" onclick = 'ounce = 16'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type = "button" value = "CAPPUCCINO" onclick = 'drink = "cappuccino"'/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type = "button" value = "Total" onclick=
              ' var price; 
                var taxRate = 0.088; 

                if (drink == "espresso") 
                {
                    price = 1.40; 
                }

                if (drink == "latte" || drink == "cappuccino") 
                { 
                    if (ounce == 8) <!-- small -->
                    {
                        price = 1.95;
                    }
                    if (ounce == 12) <!-- medium -->
                    {
                        price = 2.35;
                    }
                    if (ounce == 16) <!-- large -->
                    {
                        price = 2.75;
                    }
                } 

                if (drink == "Americano") 
                {
                    price = 1.20 + .30 * (ounce/8);
                }

                price = price + (shots - 1) * .50; 
                price = price + price * taxRate; 
                document.forms[0].price.value = "$" + Math.round( price * 100 ) / 100;
           '/>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type = "button" value = "4" onclick = 'shots = 4'/>
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type = "button" value = "  AMERICANO  " onclick = 'drink = "Americano"'/>
      </td>
      <td style="border-style : solid; border-width : medium; border-color : red">
        <input type="text" name = "price" value = "0.00" size = "5" onchange = ' '/>
      </td>
    </tr>
   </table>

   </form>
```

Comment: So, to get help with JavaScript function, did you have to post the entire HTML?

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: @PM77-1 "where can i learn javascript ."

Comment: You can't not do anything with this. You've embedded entire JavaScript script in the HTML attributes! This is really an anti-pattern. Use SCRIPT tags, You'll thank yourself later. Oh and others will be able to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all that JS in your body tag, try making a function:

`function`'s are easy, if you name em correctly. You cannot have a capital as the first letter nor spaces in function, plus none of the other special characters. functions can have an _ underscore in the name. You can also have numbers in the function name, but like capitals, they must not be the first character of the function name.

Here is how you create said function:

```
function nAm3() {

//can be any name you want, just follow those rules ^

}
```

So thats really all there is to naming functions. Calling them however is a different matter. You can call a function using HTML or inside the `<script>` tag. Inside a `<script>` tag, you can call the function like this: `nAm3();` Then the code will run. Functions only run when called. For your purposes, you'll need the `onClick` event handler you've sort-of used correctly. Instead of all that code in the `<body>` lets try the function:

```
function nAm3() {
 var price; 
                var taxRate = 0.088; 

                if (drink == "espresso") 
                {
                    price = 1.40; 
                }

                if (drink == "latte" || drink == "cappuccino") 
                { 
                    if (ounce == 8) <!-- small -->
                    {
                        price = 1.95;
                    }
                    if (ounce == 12) <!-- medium -->
                    {
                        price = 2.35;
                    }
                    if (ounce == 16) <!-- large -->
                    {
                        price = 2.75;
                    }
                } 

                if (drink == "Americano") 
                {
                    price = 1.20 + .30 * (ounce/8);
                }

                price = price + (shots - 1) * .50; 
                price = price + price * taxRate; 
                document.forms[0].price.value = "$" + Math.round( price * 100 )
}
```

Then to call it like you wanted, just put inside of your `<input>` tag:

`<input onClick="nAm3()">`

And it's that easy! I won't get into other event hadlers and function uses because this is niether a lecture nor a wiki page, but I hope this basic function knowledge helps you with your project!

Comment: Note that javascript cannot exist in the body tag, only inside script tags, but `<script>` tags can be inside the body tag too.